# How to apply style sheets to dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

this should be an easy one: I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("id","table");
        var headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        var dataRow = document.createElement("tr");
        var head = document.createElement("th");
        var data = document.createElement("td");
        head.innerHTML="head";
        data.innerHTML="data";
        headRow.appendChild(head);
        dataRow.appendChild(data);
        table.appendChild(headRow);
        table.appendChild(dataRow);
        console.log(document.styleSheets);
        table.className = "table";
        document.getElementById("test").appendChild(table);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is: The style specified in the bootstrap.min for the class "table" is never applied upon loading the side. Do I have to do something additionally? I test it in the most recent version of Safari.

Any Help?

Cheers Twerp

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Newly created elements will inherit the styles defined in your stylesheet. It's probably something else that causes the styles not to be applied.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and inspecting the element with your browser? Could show you some handy information about what's happening with the style.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vjbgdtjd/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not dynamically created issue. It is because you haven't set the class to table. As [**Bootstrap Docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) says:

You have to use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for the class to work.

To add in your answer:

```
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
thead.appendChild(headRow);
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
tbody.appendChild(dataRow);
```

Add this for a quick fix:

```
$("tr:first-child").wrap("<thead/>");
```

Your final code should look like:

```
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("id","table");
    var headRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var dataRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var head = document.createElement("th");
    var data = document.createElement("td");
    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
    thead.appendChild(headRow);
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tbody.appendChild(dataRow);
    head.innerHTML="head";
    data.innerHTML="data";
    headRow.appendChild(head);
    dataRow.appendChild(data);
    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    console.log(document.styleSheets);
    table.className = "table";
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 3):

The slight difference in styling is because Bootstrap relies on the `<tbody>` and `<thead>` elements to apply styling. If you're dynamically creating elements, you need to create these too:

```
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
thead.appendChild(headRow);
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
tbody.appendChild(dataRow);
```

Then, instead of appending `headRow` and `dataRow` directly, append the newly created elements:

```
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/219fq9yf/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function () {
        var table = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'table').addClass('table')
        var head = $('<th></th>').html('head')
        var data = $('<th></th>').html('data')
        var headRow = $('<tr></tr>').append(head)
        var dataRow = $('<tr></tr>').append(data)
        table.append(headRow)
        table.append(dataRow)
        console.log(document.styleSheets);
        $('#test').append(table);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add style sheet to dynamically added content is to use **classList**

Please refer below link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

**OR**

You can use **element.style.cssProperty**