# Bootstrap table-striped is applied

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I build a table in laravel with bootstrap html and an part is in java script. The table is correct in my browser but the bootstrap style is not working. I build the another table on this side completely in html and there is the bootstrap design.
Here is my html

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
</table>
```

and here is my java script part

```
$.get('/spieler-table?teamID=' + teamID, function(data){
            $('#myTable').empty();
            $('#myTable').append('<thead><tr>');
            $('#myTable').append('<th>Name</th>');
            $('#myTable').append('<th>Tore</th>');
            $('#myTable').append('</tr></thead>');
            $('#myTable').append('<tbody></tbody>');
            $.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){
                $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr>');
                $('#myTable tbody').append('<td>' + valueAusData.Spieler_Name + '</td>');
                $('#myTable tbody').append('<td>' + valueAusData.Tore + '</td>');
                $('#myTable tbody').append('</tr>');
            });
        });
```

Maybe the insert in tbody is not correct?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer on this question and see if it helps you: [How to apply style sheets to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069178/how-to-apply-style-sheets-to-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table structure that you're creating thru JS is incorrect (you're appending TH's to the THEAD element, TDs to the TBODY element) - try this:

```
$('#myTable').empty();
$('#myTable').append('<thead><tr>');
$('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Name</th>');
$('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Tore</th>');
$('#myTable').append('</tr></thead>');
$('#myTable').append('<tbody></tbody>');

$.each(data, function(index, valueAusData) {
      var row = '<tr><td>' + valueAusData.Spieler_Name + '</td><td>' +  valueAusData.Tore + '</td></tr>';
      $('#myTable tbody').append(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap depends on both CSS as JS. Since scripts are usually loaded after styles, you should probably use `document.write()` right inside your table element instead of after its rendering in the page DOM. I may be wrong, but that could be the case here.